# MySQL LEFT Join with multiple possibilities and Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I don't know if a similar question have been asked, but I looked fow more than hour on mysql in stackoverflow

My problem is, i have multiple tables and I need to join them with both left join and inner join in mysql

Entity table :

```
id (key) | entityName

1        |   john
2        |   harris
3        |   henry
4        |   mark
5        |   dom
```

Activity table

```
id (key) | entityID  | status

1        |       1   |   1
2        |       2   |   0
3        |       4   |   1
```

Geodata table

```
id (key) | entityID  | moment (timestamps when the entry was done)

1        |       1   | 1429542320 (smaller)
2        |       1   | 1429542331 (bigger)
3        |       2   | 1429542320 (smaller)
4        |       2   | 1429542331 (biger)
5        |       4   | 1429542331 (bigger)
```

Info table

```
id (key) | entityID | infos | date 

   1     |      1   |  xxx  |   today
   2     |      1   |  xxx  |   yesterday
   3     |      2   |  xxx  |   today
   4     |      2   |  xxx  |   yesterday
   5     |      3   |  xxx  |   yesterday
   6     |      5   |  xxx  |   today
   7     |      5   |  xxx  |   yesterday
   8     |      5   |  xxx  |   tomorrow
```

So basically, I need every Entities that has an info for today
Moreover, if their status is true (or 1) (from activity table), show me their date in geodata table.

So this is what i've got :

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.entityName, 
       i.infos, 
       a.status, 
       MAX(g.moment) -- but the max only if status =1 
  FROM entities AS e
  LEFT JOIN activity AS a ON a.entityID = e.id
  LEFT JOIN geodata AS g ON g.entityID = e.id
 INNER JOIN infos AS i ON e.id = i.entityID
 WHERE i.date = 'today'
 GROUP BY e.id
```

I want every entities that has an info about today, but some of them have activity too, so i want to show it (if it doesn't just let the left join put NULL) If the status is 0, I don't need the moment, but if its true, I only need the bigger one (its numbers, so Max() should do it but it breaks)

The expected results is :

```
id (key) | entityName | infos |   status |   MAX(moment) | ..other columns

   1     |     john   |  xxx  |      1   | 1429542331 (the bigger one)
   2     |     harris |  xxx  |      0   | NULL
   5     |     dom    |  xxx  |     NULL | NULL
```

If someone can help me, I'll be very thankful :)
PS.: Sorry for my english, it isn't my first language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the 
`MAX(g.moment)` 
to 
`IF(a.status<>1, NULL, MAX(g.moment))`

or alternately change `LEFT JOIN geodata AS g ON g.entityID = e.id` to `LEFT JOIN geodata AS g ON a.entityID = e.id AND a.status = 1`

Which one is faster will probably depend on your actual data; the second may be faster as less records are joined, but the more complicated join condition it uses might slow down the joining.

Comment: It worked! But it tooks so much time. First method took about 20 seconds and second one about 7 seconds. Considering I fire this query on load of a php page, its really long. I only have about 2k data in each tables, and I know it'll grow. Is there a method to do it faster or ?

Comment: Are your tables indexed appropriately? (Should have indices on: infos.date, entityID on all tables with it, but the geodata table should have a single index on `entityID,status` in that order.)

Comment: Also, since I don't always trust query optimizers, you might want to rearrange the JOINs so that `infos` is the first table.

Comment: I did, and it took approx 1.4 seconds. I thank both of you guys !

Comment: Did which, added the indices or rearranged the join order?

Comment: rearranged the join order